# Android phone lost, Data wipe after password change

Tags: security, hardware, android-device-manager, remote-wipe

Here's an urgent situation regarding phone robbery:

1. My android phone (note 8) gets robbed and as far as i know it has not lost its way to some general person. It was robbed by force, so people handling that can misuse it, so am very concerned.
2. It all happened in a very unexpected fashion and very fast. In a hurry to secure device, i immediately login to my nearest computer when possible (after 15-20 mins), googled how to clean the lost device and followed the steps. From the very moment it showed these two options:

   a. ) Play Sound

   b.) Enable secure and erase

I repeatedly click on enable 'secure and erase', google showed an alert that a request to secure and release has been sent.  But i guess robbers would have switched the phone off, so google might not have been able to delete it immediately.

3. I read that as a first step, i must change my account password. So immediately i changed my account password from the phone.
4. Meanwhile, i kept trying for secure and erase and searching for other safe options. On searching for how would i confirm if the device have been wiped, i came to find that after 'secure and erase' google supposedly sends an email to ask for further multiple options.

Now here's my concern:

5. Having already changed the password, when those robbers do turn the phone on, will google would be able to still secure and erase the phone? Or have i hurt my own cause after changing the password immediately.

The emails contain lots of personal information as i have been a heavy user of email on phone and of professional email as well. Also the phone's gallery contains more than 2k photographs of family members and close friends. Am really concerned about this. I know similar question have been asked before but the answers to that arent very clear. So I'll be really greatful if on or more of you can share any further information on this.

Comment: The phone will be erased as soon as the phone is connected to some form of internet (either through mobile data or WiFi). Changing the password does not effect this procedure, the device will still be wiped.